# named parameter binding with sql-wildcard not working

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm using the node-sqlite3 package to access my db.
I'm trying to get rows from a Clients table with this code:

```
var st = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM Clients where name LIKE '%$name%'");
st.all({ $name: "test" }, function (err, rows) {
      console.log("this: " + JSON.stringify(this));
      if (err)
        console.log(err);
      else {
        console.log("found: " + JSON.stringify(rows));
      }
});
```

Output of err is this:

```
{ [Error: SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column index out of range] errno: 25, code: 'SQLITE_RANGE' }
```

The query works and doesn't throw errors when I change the sql to `SELECT * FROM Clients where name LIKE '%$name%'`. So I guess the problem is, that `node-sqlite3` tries to find a variable called `$name%` or something like that in the object passed as first parameter to `Statement#all`.
I've searched the [API doc](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#statementallparam--callback) for more hints about this, but couldn't find any.

Do I need to escape something? How do I get my query to work with named binding and the sql wildcards `%`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the way bindings work.

You can have

```
SELECT * FROM Clients where name LIKE $name
```

and

```
var name = "%"+"test"+"%";
..
{ $name: name }
```

bound variables are negociated with the backend database as a "whole" variable and you should not confuse this with variable replacement.

you should also be able to use the concatenate function of sqlite (not tested) :

```
SELECT * FROM Clients where name LIKE '%'||$name||'%'
..
{ $name: test }
```

Comment: the sqlite concat version seemed like the nicest to me and it worked. thanks :)